# VBA Replace cell if it contains certain text in a given column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, find-and-replace

I'm an absolute beginner at VBA and need some help with find and replace automation.

I need a code that that can find cells in a column that contain certain partial text and replace that cell with a value and another cell in that row with another value. I would also like to do this when I press a CommandButton from a different workbook. Also, can I do this with multiple conditions?

This is the code I have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Set ws2 = Workbooks("Hills").Worksheets("Section Properties")

With ws2
    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lRow
        If .Cells("B", i) = "\X2\00D8\X0\20 ROD" Then
            .Cells("B", i) = "Round 20"
            .Cells("C", i) = "SolidMet"
    End If
Next i
End With

With ws2
    For i = 1 To lRow
    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Cells("B", i) = "\X2\00D8\X0\16 ROD" Then
            .Cells("B", i) = "Round 16"
            .Cells("C", i) = "SolidMet"
    End If
Next i
End With

End Sub
```

At the moment, nothing happens and I'm not sure how to fix it.

This is my spreadsheet:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

In cell B12, "\X2\00D8\X0\20 ROD" changes to "20 Round" and adds "SolidMet" to C12.
Similarly, in cell B22, "\X2\00D8\X0\16 ROD" changes to "16 Round" and adds "SolidMet" to C22.

Comment: First thing i'd do is throw in a `msgbox` somewhere near the top just to say `Hello world` so you know it's being called. Second, I'd add some `debug.print` statements in to validate what the code is doing; e.g. `debug.print i` in your loop, so you can see it iterating. You could also add some breakpoints in so you can see if a line gets hit.

Comment: Found the issue. I mistook the Cells property syntax as Cells.(col, row), instead of the correct syntax Cells.(row, col). Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would encourage you to post an answer to your question, with your modified code and an explanation of it was going wrong and what you did to fix it.